# Postponing search until template load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ember.js, sinatra

I want to make a request to a server to get a bunch of news articles based off of what the user clicks on (recent, trending, etc).  I'd like to be able to load the page first and show a loading bar while I wait for the response from the API.  What I have, and although it works and returns the JSON data I need, will wait until the response comes back from the server before loading anything.  This is all it is so far:

What I want to achieve is the following:  Load up an empty array of objects, and then make API calls to articles incrementally (let's say grab all the articles from this hour, then last hour, then the hour before, and so on) and whenever I retrive articles populate the view (I'm assuming I can just inject them into a controller somehow) however I'm getting lost on the Emberisms on how to add to that array of objects.  I think I need to make an ArrayController and then create a model in said array, then call a function to add to it, but as I said I'm lost as to how to add items into that controller on the fly

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('today');
});

App.TodayRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
     model: function() {
        return $.getJSON('/today');
     }
});
```

---

To elaborate a bit on the reasoning for my question - I'm confused on how to approach this with ember.  I'm familiar on how to do something like this using jquery, however I'm trying to learn the framework and am having a little bit of trouble originally knowing what the division of labor is between the two.  I know the actual AJAX requests should be jquery, but I want to do as much as possible in Ember.  If this however is something that should be done by jquery though, then that is fine as well!

Comment: you question is slightly to broad, let's dissect the problem a little. 1. can you show how you JSON format returned by the backend looks like? Another question might arise after seeing the JSON format: 2. will you be able to change how the API returns the data if necessary? And one more 3. do you use ember-data?

Comment: @intuitivepixel the JSON I'm returning is an array of objects, each with a site, a headline, and an article.  It's through the NYTimes api so unfortunately, no, I wont be able to alter it, although I can process it in ruby if .  Currently I'm not using ember-data - for no reason other than I havent found an explicit reason to use it (that is a solution that includes it).  I don't know if you read my most recent update but I feel as if I outlined the problem fairly well in that - if not let me know what else I'm leaving out.

Comment: Sorry, since I'm new to ember I dont exactly know what information is too much, too little, or appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - and like everything with ember, it was very simple.  I used some blank fixture data, then defined my controller as below.

```
App.ArticleRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Article.find();
  }
})
```

Then upon pageload I call a method focused around

```
App.Article.createRecord({
    // Attributes, pulling from the returned JSON
})
```

Simple! :)

Answer (score 0):

The getJSON method looks to have a callback function on success you could use, something like this maybe?

```
App.TodayRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
     model: function() {
        $.getJSON('/today', function(data) {
           // hide loading here
           / data is the JSON returned
        });
     }
});
```

Check out this link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: While this would work, it seems as if I'm avoiding ember by implementing it with pure jQuery.  Plus, I think there is a better solution than just having it as an Ember model but I'm unsure as to what that may be.